# how to access list of elements inside another list of element using xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

I have an xml which has list of elements inside another list of element

```
<root>
<lists>
  <list>
     <L1subroot>
        <clists>
           <clist>
             <id>1</id>
             <name>xxx</name>
           </clist>
           <clist> 
            <id>2</id>                                
            <name>xxx</name>
           </clist>
        </clists>
     </L1subroot>
  </list>
  <list>
  </list>
</lists>
</root>
```

I need to loop through the element 'clists' and get the name value inside each clist element. when i give xpath like '//root/lists/list/L1subroot/clists/clist'  and try to read the value of name element im getting blank value. can anyone help me how to read the element value of an list inside another list element in xslt

XSLT file im using

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="//root/lists/list/L1subroot/clists/clist">
        <xsl:element name="Info">
           <xsl:element name="name">
               <xsl:value-of select="name">
           </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you are currently having trouble with, please? And also show the output you are expecting to achieve? Thank you!

Comment: That's not well=formed XML.

Comment: updated both xml and xslt

Comment: Your xslt is not well-formed, as the `xsl:value-of` is not properly closed. Although if it was closed, it should then output values (See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcH). Does your XML have any namespace declarations in (of the form `xmlns="..."`) by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it works fine. i gave the xpath in uppercase and it caused the error :P